# How would I make an equivalent of this PHP line in bash?

Tags: php, bash

Here is the PHP line:

```
intval(substr($strIn,$i, 2), 32);
```

I'm trying to convert this to bash, first I know that `intval` is not needed because of how bash handles variables, so I don't need the first part, however I have read about `substr`, but I can't figure out what it does in this case. Does anyone know what the equivalent in bash would be?

Comment: If you've read the [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) docs and the [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) ones too, what's ambiguous here?

Comment: I think you aren't understanding what `intval()` is doing, so I've added an answer that is actually the bash equivalent of the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`substr($strIn, $i, 2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) returns 2 characters from `$strIn`, starting with offset `$i`. For example, `substr('foobar', 3, 2)` returns `'ba'`.

The equivalent in bash is:

```
STR=foobar
echo ${STR:3:2}
```

If the start offset is not fixed but it is stored in a variable then it's just like this:

```
STR=foobar
i=2
echo ${STR:$i:2}          # It displays: ob
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP is loosely typed; there are few occasions you'd need to explicitly convert a string to an integer with [`intval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php). But, one of those occasions is if you're using a different radix. Note the second parameter to `intval()` is 32, meaning it's being converted from base 32. Of course, bash can also do this:

```
strIn=foobar
i=2
echo $((32#${strIn:$i:2}))
```

Note this is using [bash-specific base conversion](http://phoxis.org/2012/07/12/builtin-bash-any-base-to-decimal-conversion/) and won't necessarily work in other shells.

Test results:

```
mike ~ $ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $strIn = 'foobar';
php > $i = 4;
php > echo intval(substr($strIn,$i, 2), 32);
347
php > exit
mike ~ $ strIn="foobar"
mike ~ $ i=4
mike ~ $ echo $((32#${strIn:$i:2}))
347
mike ~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve this is using cut:

substr($strIn, $i, $length) equivalent:

```
end=$(expr $i + $length)
echo $strIn | cut -b $i-$end
```