# Is it possible to make an identical an equivalent line in bash of this php line?

Tags: php, bash

I have this PHP code:

```
$numIn = intval(substr($strIn,$i, 2), 32);
```

Now, with the `substr` part, I think this works:

```
numIn=${STR:$i:2}
```

I read somewhere that `intval` was not needed in bash, but this doesn't not produce the same output as the code in php, does anyone know what to do?

Comment: What did you intend to do in PHP with passing 32 as argument?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would I make an equivalent of this PHP line in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35158737/how-would-i-make-an-equivalent-of-this-php-line-in-bash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ale almost there. Just do a:

```
numIn=$(( 32#${STR:$i:2} ))
```

which will convert your value in base32 to base10 integer. For example try:

```
echo $(( 32#a0 ))
```

which outputs:

```
320
```